# TypeError: path should be path-like or io.BytesIO, not <class 'shiny.reactive._reactives.Value'>

Tags: python, py-shiny

I am creating a simple shiny app for a dog breed classifier. The user would be able to upload a picture of a dog, and then have the shiny app display the predicted breed.

A simplified version of the app code is as follows:

```
from shiny import App, Inputs, Outputs, Session, reactive, render, ui
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pickle

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.input_file("dog_pic", "Upload your dog picture!", accept=[".jpeg"], multiple=False),
    ui.output_text("txt")

)

def server(input, output, session):

    # PROCESSING IMAGE:
    @reactive.Calc
    def parsed_file():
         image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(input.dog_pic, target_size=(224, 224))
         input_arr = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
         input_arr = np.array([input_arr])
         input_arr = input_arr.astype('float32') / 255.
         return input_arr

    # PARSING IMAGE THROUGH TO MODEL
    @output
    @render.text
    def txt():

        model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model')
        dog_prediction = model.predict(parsed_file())
        return f"Predicted dog breed is {dog_prediction}!"

app = App(app_ui, server)
```

The error I am getting is:
[image]

What does this mean?
Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick note: Don't use `input` as variable name. It shadows the built-in input function. Otherwise, you might need to cast `input.dog_pic` in `parsed_file` to string or something. You should check the actual type by printing the value before using it or checking it with a debugger if possible.

Comment: Also, why did you add the `R` tag? This is pure Python is it not?

Comment: @Raphael thanks! I'll change that - the R tag was by accident, I think I accidentally clicked on recommended tags!

Answer (score 0):

Your functions `parsed_file()` and `txt()` are called as soon as you start the shiny app. But at that time your file is not yet loaded. You have to add something like "if file available then ... else ...".

Answer (score 0):

Here, the input.dog_pic does not return a string or path type. So need to typecast accordingly to a string.

Answer (score 0):

The error says you're giving a shiny object instead of a path. Calling `input.dog_pic` gives the shiny object handle/function, but calling `input.dog_pic()` gives the value stored by that object. Since you want the path stored inside, use `input.dog_pic()` as the path to import your image.

See for example your use of `parsed_file()` in your render text function. The parentheses tell shiny to evaluate the function and return just the value.

If you still have problems, you may need to add some calls to shiny's `req` function. Include it as one of the things you import from shiny and add `req(input.dog_pic())` as the first line in your `parse_file` function. Do the same for `req(parsed_file())` in your `txt` function. These will tell your functions to require those values before they attempt the calculation. Fixing the parentheses as stated above still seems necessary to me.